# Why does poo smell more after someone is back from a trek/hike?

Tags: human-waste

Blaming it on my roommate all the way.

He goes for a 3 day hike, whenever he is back, he is tired, thats obvious and evident. The night he comes in, he goes to washroom (for poo) and his poo smells real bad.

Is it common/normal?

(I too face the same issue once in a while).
What might he be doing wrong? Is it related to hydrating habits and/or diet?

Hydration: Never dehydrated really. Water intake might be a bit low as compared to a regular day, but manageable.
Diet: Mostly white bread and pickle/jam/sauce or butter as lunch. Lots of tomatoes, carrots and cucumbers to munch on. Some variant of steamed rice as the dinner.

Comment: Does your protein intake change when you're hiking compared to when you're at home? What's your/his diet like while trekking?

Comment: @ShemSeger: Sorry mate, I should have added those details earlier. Please refer the edits.

Comment: Shem is right about eating a lot of protein - people who use protein shakes talk about it a fair bit

Comment: He has not taken a good porcelain dump in 3 days and lets it rip.

Comment: Some won't like those questions but for me it's not disgusting or so. Similarly and most likely related to OPs question I observed the increase in flatulences while hiking. Mostly you won't have a balanced diet I guess.

Comment: @paparazzi's point might be an extreme version of a simple effect. Disrupting the regular routine means waste hangs around in the system longer, allowing more time for smells to build up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even in a vegetarian diet, changes in diet result in digestion changes.  Gas is created by [flora and fauna in the digestive tract.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gut_flora) If you exclude something or add something at the top of the digestive tract, it would be normal to expect a different result in the end.

Given the list of trail food you provided, one possibility is an increase in butter consumption on the trail.  If the person is [Lactose intolerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactose_intolerance) even a moderate increase can result in the symptoms you describe.

**Solution** Identify which foods are added or removed from the diet while hiking. One at a time, restore or remove the different items from the trail diet until you identify which is the cause.